# What bots do each of the Pros spawn?

Tags: monday-night-combat

When a pro buys bots at the station, what is spawned?  Exact numbers would be nice.

For instance I know the assassin spawns (3?) gremlins, the assault spawns buzzers, and the gunner spawns bouncers (and a few other bots too?)

Does this change depending on the map?  Is there any random variation to the #?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not appear to be any variations to the numbers.

For the PC version:

- Assassin spawns 4 Gremlins
- Assault spawns 6(?) Buzzers
- Gunner spawns 1 Bouncer
- Sniper spawns 3 Scramblers
- Support spawns 1 Gapshot
- Tank spawns 1 Bouncer

Comment: Are you sure about the gunner spawns?  Either it was a coincidence, or maybe I was too drunk at the time, but I remember seeing some slims/blackjacks too when I spawned things as a gunner

Comment: @yx01: Slims and Black Jacks automatically spawn, as does the occasional Jackbot XL.  Both teams bots of those 3 types spawn at the exact same time.